# find all the functions $f:\mathbb{R}→\mathbb{R}$ such that $f(1)=1$ and $f(xy+f(x))=xf(y)+f(x)$

Tags: functional-equations

here is what i did
i found that $f(f(0))=f(0)$

i need to prove that f is injective so that $f(0)$ will be equal to $0$

Hence $f(f(x))=xf(0)+f(x)$
so if $f(0)=0$ and $f$ is injective $f(x)=x$
please don't give me the solution , just give me a hint to how to prove that $f$ is injective

Also , i found that $$f(x+f(x))=x+f(x)$$ i don't if that relation means that $f$ is injective

SORRY , GUYS! I FOUND A SOLUTION WITHOUT INJECTIVITY

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$x=1$ and $y=0$ yields

$$f(f(1))=f(0)+f(1)$$

Use $f(1)=1$.

**Added** Setting $y=0$ you get 
$$f(f(x))=f(x)$$

Next, set $y=\frac{1}{x}$ and use $f(f(x))=f(x)$ and $f(x+1)=f(x)+1$.

Comment: I think this still doesn't address injectivity does it?

Comment: yeah but now i have $f(x)=f(f(x))$ 
so i have to prove injectivity

Comment: and i also have $f(y+1)=f(y)+1$

Comment: @user600785 Check the addition.